# Floating point exception error while finding ''Perfect Number" using user defined functions

Tags: c++, floating-point-exceptions

I have to write a program with checks "Perfect Numbers" in a specific range given by the user. I made a user-defined function to check if a particular number is a perfect number. If it is then 1 is returned, if not then 0. And then I use an if statement to print out the perfect number in the main program. The issue I'm getting is a floating point exception error. I have no idea what to do now. I'll be really grateful for some help. :).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int isPerfect(int n);

int main(){
    int num=0,perfectCheck=0;
    cout<<"Enter a value for N: ";
    cin>>num;
    cout<<"Perect numbers between 1 and "<<num<<" are : "<<endl;
    for(int i;i<=num;i++){
        perfectCheck=isPerfect(i);
        if(perfectCheck==1){
              cout<<i<<endl;
        }   
    }
    return 0;
}

int isPerfect(int n){
    int sum,mod;
    for(int i;i<n;i++){
        mod=n%i;
        if(mod==0){
            sum=sum+i;
        }
    }
    if(sum==n){
         return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please enter your error?

Comment: Where is `int i` initialized with your for loop?

Comment: @user0042 they are in the pre for statement. By default they should be zero.

Comment: Unable to replicate your error.

Comment: I used 2 different compilers as I thought there was somethign wrong with my compiler. In Dev C++ I got a really weird out which made no sense. and in the other compiler it gave me a floating point error. Wait I'll attach the link to my output. sorry

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14g1jtjPg_QksLnF3zodfepiVxbXTpHeU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You have UB: Local variables are not default initialized in C++! `i`, `sum`, `mod` are not `0`

Comment: Even after initializing them I am still getting the same output

Comment: @king_nak thank you soo much. I forgot to initialize the ones in the isPerfect Function.  Now it works. Thank youuuu!!!! :)

Comment: @Jake _"By default they should be zero"_ That's the problem of course.

Comment: @user0042 You are right my bad

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop in isPerfect function should start from 1, because n%0 is undefined behavior.

Comment: Still getting the same issue. I think there might be something wrong in the for loop used in the main function.

Comment: Initialize i in the main loop to 1 too. and initialize sum to 0

Comment: Yes I got it :). Thank you soo much.